# Spring XD 1.2.1 Container Jolokia access

Tags: spring-xd

What is the default HTTP port for Jolokia access in a Spring XD 1.2.1 container? We have had Jolokia working before on previous XD versions but something seems to have changed.

We have changed the XD_JMX_ENABLED value in servers.yml ie

```
XD_JMX_ENABLED: true
endpoints:
  jolokia:
    enabled: ${XD_JMX_ENABLED:false}
  jmx:
    enabled: ${XD_JMX_ENABLED:false}
    uniqueNames: true
```

With this we can access JMX directly by setting -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port etc. I assumed the HTTP port would be 9393 like Spring XD Admin but this doesn't seem to be the case. 
Is there a default or do we have to uncomment and set

```
#spring:
#  profiles: container
#management:
#  port: 0
```

Also the documentation seems wrong here, it mentions port 9080, then in the URL beneath it uses 9393.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **CONTROL_MGMT_PORT** environment variable too.

For *nix based setups /etc/sysconfig/springxd

I'm using it in 1.2.1.RELEASE version without issue.